# Handle local notification only when the user clicks on it

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilocalnotification

I'm actually working on an iOS application in which I need to handle notifications.
I'm currently using local notifications, and I need to redirect to different viewControllers when I click on a notification. 
My problem is that for now the redirection is made every time I receive a notification and the application does not wait for me to click on it.
I tried many solutions and I always have the same problem.

So I'm wondering : Is it possible to redirect to specific views only when the user click on the notification and not when it appears ?

Thanks you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try as below. I have also written code, which may help you.

- When application is in **Active** state : you may show alert and ask user for redirect to different screen or not.
- When application is in **Inactive** state : you may redirect user
  directly to required screen because they coming in app via tap on
  notification.

  ```
  -(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
  {
       UIApplicationState state = [application applicationState];
       if (state == UIApplicationStateActive)
          {
          UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Alert" message:@"Your Message" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"View", nil];
          [alert show];
          }
       if (state == UIApplicationStateInactive)
          {
             // Redirect User to your required screen.
          }
  }
  -(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
  {
        if (buttonIndex == 1)
          {
            // Redirect User to your required screen.
          }
  }
  ```

Comment: I had tried something similar,but it wasn't working. I think my problem was somewhere else, I didn't find where, so I restart a new project. I used your code and it works very well ! Thanks you very much for taking time to help me !

Answer (score 0):

You can judge the app state when you receive local notification using `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationState]`

If the app is in active state, you can just show a UIAlertView indicating user receiving the local notification.So user click on the alertView,you can redirect the viewController.

I hope my answer may help you.